# Removing XML attributes with XML_Serializer

Tags: php

Hopefully there's one or two experienced users of the XML_Serializer PEAR class here

I'm parsing an XML file with XML_Serializer

I'm using this PEAR class so that I can grab the entire contents and put it into an array (why is another story for another time)

At the moment it is also taking the attributes and their values of the tags like so:

```
<prod id="88966064" pre_order="no" web_offer="no" in_stock="no" stock_quantity="0">
<pId>608</pId>
<isbn>0000000000000</isbn>
```

And adding them to the returned array like this:

```
XML_Serializer_Tag] => Array(
         [id] => 88966064
         [pre_order] => no
         [web_offer] => no
         [in_stock] => no
         [stock_quantity] => 0
)
```

Are there any options in XML_Serializer that allows me to use the XML data without the attributes and just the tags and the data inbetween them, ie only?

```
<pId>608</pId>
<isbn>0000000000000</isbn>
```

The data is dynamic so a solution of removing them individually is no goer

Answer (score 0):

XML_Unserializer defaults its 'parseAttributes' option to FALSE [1].  Try to explicitly set it to FALSE and see if that helps.

[1] -- https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.xml.xml-serializer.xml-unserializer.options.php